# Как найти наибольшее значение

Tags: sql

Может кто-то знает как это сделать?

Найти status по наибольшей дате (idate) для каждого (уникального) договора (id_dogovor)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY id_dogovor ORDER BY idate DESC)`

Comment: Чтобы с Вами здесь стали разговаривать (здесь очень не любят халяву) к ясно сформулированной проблеме нужно приложить попытку ее решения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Главное - чтобы она была способна понять ответ...

Comment: @Akina а вдруг у неё СУБД не поддерживающая оконные функции?

Comment: @Akina, кстати Вам удалось дать ответ в единственно правильной форме - кому можно помочь, тот все поймет и сделает, а для любителя халявы это китайская грамота :)